# Can't run parallel zgrep with regex

Tags: grep, regular-expression, gnu-parallel

When I run this:

```
find . -name "my.log*.gz" -print | \
parallel zgrep -e "\(text1\|text2\).*Exception"
```

to find all lines that match `/(text1|text2).*Exception/` in all files in the folder, I get this error message:

```
zsh:1: no matches found: (text1|text2).*Exception
```

From the error message, I think `(text1|text2).*Exception` is being treated as a file name. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just to be sure: what `parallel` command are you running? The command from the 'moreutils' package, or the 'GNU parallel' command from the 'parallel' package?

Comment: Note that `grep` expects one or more filenames as arguments on the commandline, or file contents on stdin. In contrast, your command feeds filenames on stdin (via the pipe), which will not work. In addition, if you are using the `parallel` command from the `moreutils` package, the syntax is off.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-E` for extended regex

```
find . -name "my.log*.gz" -print | \
parallel zgrep -E "\(text1\|text2\).*Exception"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need more quoting:

```
find . -name "*.gz" -print |
  parallel -q zgrep -e "\(text1\|text2\).*Exception"
```

Use `-vv` and `--dr` to see what is really being run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `parallel` command from the `moreutils` package, your command could be simplified like this:

```
parallel zgrep -e "\(text1\|text2\).*Exception" -- my.log*.gz
```

This will run parallel instances of `zgrep`, one for each file matching the shell pattern `my.log*.gz`. Note that the pattern is expanded by the shell before the command is executed. Hence there is no need for a separate invocation of `find`.

Use `zgrep` with option `-H` if you want to know *which file* matches.